# XmlPullParser exception when creating new instance in Java on Tomcat7 server

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

I am working on a dynamic web app using Eclipse with Tomcat 7 and jre 7.  I receive the following exception when attempting to parse an xml string:

**could not load any factory class (even small or full default implementation); nested exception is: org.kxml2.io.XmlReader**

XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

which is part of the org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory namespace.

I have put the xmlpull_1_0_5.jar into the Tomcat lib folder and restart it.  I have also put the file in the WEB-INF lib folder.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the one you have and use the KXML2 implementation. Download from here: [link](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/)

More [Info](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)